# Scaling dollar amounts isn't working as expected

Tags: python, pandas

With only being able to import numpy and pandas, I need to do the following:
Scale the `medianIncome` to express the values in $10,000 of dollars (example: `150000` will become `15`, `30000` will become `3`, `15000` will become `1.5`, etc)
So this is what I've tried:

```
temp_housing['medianIncome'].replace( '[(]','-',   regex=True ).astype(float))
```

When I do this, it doesn't really do anything but change it to a float. No real affect. I'm not sure what I'm missing, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried dividing it by 10000? e.g. `temp_housing['medianIncome'].replace( '[(]','-',   regex=True ).astype(float)) / 10000` ?

Comment: Instead of the regex approach are you able to just divide medianIncome by 10_000?

Comment: Nice nick even included a snippet for you. Hope that works

Comment: So simple. Thank you, no I didn't think of it based on the wording, but makes total sense.

Comment: That definitely worked, appreciated! I just can't get it assigned to the actual column. So, it's giving me the correct results, just not putting it in the actual df.